# Numbering a section supplement

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I want to have a section and a supplement/continuation of it underneath it as another section with the same number and '* after it. Don't really know how to explain it, basically something like this

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\section{First section}
\section*{I'*. First section continued}
```

Which would translate to

I. First section

I'*. First section continued

Don't know how to do it other than with \section*.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code provides `\sectionsupplement{<title>}` that sets a `\section*` with the appropriate numbering and suffix:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\AtBeginDocument{\sloppy}% Just for this example

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\newcommand{\sectionsupplement}[1]{%
  \section*{\thesection'*\quad #1}% Set supplemental section as \section*
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]

\sectionsupplement{First section continued}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Note that the `\sectionsupplement` doesn't appear in the ToC since it's set as a `\section*` internally. If you want it to appear in the ToC as well, you can add it:

[image]

```
% ...
\newcommand{\sectionsupplement}[1]{%
  \section*{\thesection'*\quad #1}% Set supplemental section as \section*
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection'*}#1}% Add to ToC
}
% ...
```

Comment: That was very helpful as well, appreciate it. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently. Don't bother with `\section*`. Use normal section and redefine the counter. Possibly using a different command.

---

Here is the code and a preview.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\contsection}[1]{\addtocounter{section}{-1}%
  \section{\emph{(continued)} #1}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Normal section}

\contsection{Continuation section}

\section*{Starred section}

\section{Normal section again}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you fiddle with your copy of `\section` definition long enough, you will be able to add stars or primes to the number, which is defined by `\thesection` in the code. It depends on what *is* your current `\section` definition, however.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Kinda got it to work with
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}*'} 
    \setcounter{section}{-1}, but this is much nicer.